# Javascript Evaluating a string as a mathematical, Contains "()"

Tags: javascript

```
var temp = '1000*(2-1)/2';
```

How do I parse and evaluate a mathematical expression in a string `('1000*(2-1)/2')`. have "()". using javascript

Comment: You can use `eval(temp)`, but be careful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use **eval**. Just be aware should then sanitize the string with a regex first to handle **errors**:

[eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

```js
var temp = '1000*(2-1)/2';
// strip anything other than digits, (), -+/* and .
var str = temp.replace(/[^-()\d/*+.]/g, '');
console.log(eval(str));
```

Or you could use **Function-constructor**:

[Function doc Mozilla developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

```js
var temp = '1000*(2-1)/2';

function calc(value) {
  return new Function('return ' + value)();
}

console.log( calc(temp) );
```